# Matplotlib DateFormatter behavior change: unable to plot both major and minor tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm to plot some data with datetime data on the x axis, with different formatting for major and minor labels. Using version 3.1.1, I cannot find a way to display both major and minor tick labels at the major intervals.

MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
print(mpl.__version__)
time = pd.date_range(start='2013-11-08 12:00',end='2013-11-09 12:00',freq='10min')
np.random.seed(12345)
u = pd.Series(np.random.random_sample(len(time)), index=time)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(u.index, u)
ax.set_xlim((time[0],time[-1]))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=range(24),interval=3))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H%M'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=2,maxticks=3))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('\n%Y-%m-%d'))
fig.savefig('test_{:s}.png'.format(mpl.__version__))
```

Before (matplotlib version 3.0.2):
[version 3.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhCPn.png)

After (matplotlib version 3.1.1):
[version 3.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu8Jr.png)

I've also tried changing the major formatter to `mdates.DateFormatter('%H%M\n%Y-%m-%d')` but unfortunately the labels are misaligned vertically.

Does anybody have any ideas/suggestions, hacky or otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: Also see [API changes: major-minor-tick-collisions](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/api_changes.html#major-minor-tick-collisions)

Comment: Thanks, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest!